# Low-side push-pull transistor of MOSFET gate driver damaged

Tags: buck, mosfet-driver, gate-driving, inductive, push-pull

I have a buck converter as shown in the given figure (48 V output):

[image: Buck converter schematic]

At rated loads the buck converter operates correctly as expected. When I test the circuit with the over-current and the short-circuit cases, there seems to be a problem in the inductor current as shown in the figure:

[image: Non-triangular inductor current]

Also, it is interesting to note that the period of the inductor current changes in this abnormal condition. This can be see in the figure. [image: Normal case with correct period] compared to [image: Abnormal case with higher period], [image: Abnormal case 1 with higher period] and [image: Abnormal case 2 with lower period]

Also, there was some damage in the wire bond at the COM pin of the driver and at Vss. There was no damage at the high'side part of the driver.

Incorrect triggering of the MOSFET occurs. After testing the buck converter multiple times (40 to 50, maybe more), the converter is damaged. Specifically, the driver is damaged. When an optical inspection was done of the gate driver, it was observed that the low-side push-pull transistor was damaged. The specific transistor that is damaged is shown in this figure:

[image: Damaged transistor marked in the picture]

What could have caused this damage?

How does an increase in load current affect the voltages and currents at the gate?

These results are obtained from the MCM which has this entire circuit as a bare die. When the same circuit is made as a PCB, I do not see any problem with the inductor current, and I see correct operation at all operating loads.

MCM is more compact than the PCBA and has different layouts.

MCM: Multi chip module. During the over-current case the controller shuts down the PWM in a few μs depending on the level of over-current.

The Vgs for high and low side is given in this figures:

[image: Red is high-side Vgs and green is low-side Vgs]

Red is high-side Vgs and green is low-side Vgs.

[image: Vgs]

Note: I had not compensated the probe, so I got the wrong magnitude of Vgs.

Comment: If channel 1 is inductor current, what are the other two channels? What's the saturation current of your inductor? How are you measuring current and tripping on OCP?

Comment: Channel 3  and 4 are the output voltage (48V) and gate supply voltage respectively.

Comment: Measure Vgs and Vds instead.

Comment: These are the results from the MCM, so the entire circuit is bare die and inaccessible. On the PCBA counterpart, Vgs measured seem to be fine. Since, the PCBA does not show these non triangular inductor current waveform. So, PCBA is working correctly.

Comment: What's MCM? Please show Vgs and Vgs from where you can measure them. How have you implemented OCP?

Comment: MCM  : Multi chip module. During the over-current case the controller shuts down the PWM in few us depending on level of over-current.

Comment: Please show it in schematic and oscillogram. You haven't responded to my question on inductor saturation current.

Comment: The saturation current is around 11A.

Comment: Using a 250-volt MOSFET for a 200-volt supply; I wonder if you are not breaking down during switching transients.

Comment: At 13.4 A, no wonder it starts to duck-tail. What's your OCP situation? Still waiting on Vds and Vgs oscillograms.

Comment: I have no OCP at the driver side. How much safety factor to keep when selecting the MOSFET breakdown voltage?  But why do I not get the similar inductor current with the PCB? The inductors are the same in both the circuits and placed on separate support board.

Comment: You need at least 50 % voltage rating above your max instantaneous peak voltage to have margins on your side. If you don't have any OCP, your inductor will saturate and your MOSFETs blow up if you short the output. Please measure Vds in the same oscillogram as Vgs.

Comment: Just a question. Does the switching behavior change when the current to be switched is in the over-current range?

Comment: Yes, that's the very purpose of OCP.

Comment: What sort of controller are you using to feed the signals into the IR2110? If you're just putting fixed square waves in from a function generator or similar, it's no wonder an overload kills it. Inductor saturation dramatically changes system dynamics, and you need a controller that can deal with it (this is essentially the OCP winny is talking about, though there are other forms of overcurrent protection).

Comment: I am using cascaded controller. (Inner current control and outer voltage control). The OCP is that, when the overcurrent is detected, the PWM is stopped after a delay of 50us.